# GLTF animations distorted after export

Tags: export, gltf

When I export my character from Blender to GLTF and view the result in the GLTF viewer, the character looks distorted:

[image]

However, this only happens if the animation is not selected in the Action editor when I export. If the animation is selected, then the character looks normal:

[image]

This affects all animations in the GLTF file - only the animation that is currently selected in Blender when I do the export looks correct. Note that I tried several different GLTF viewers, so it’s not a problem with the viewer.

I thought perhaps the problem might be that some bones were not getting initialized in the animation, but that is not the case - every bone is keyframed at frame 0 with location, rotation and scale.

Comment: Suggest reporting a bug: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. I've been working with the maintainer to resolve it. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1539